# How do I change pointBackgroundColor in Line segment on ChartJS?

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm trying to change pointBackGround color in line segment part of a graph but it appear to only works for borderColor. Here's my code. Does anyone know how to change them? I'm using chart.js version 3.1.1 by the way.

```
const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            label: `${props.stationSelected.selected.label2}`,
            borderColor: '#feb1c3',
            backgroundColor: '#feb1c3',
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointBackgroundColor: '#feb1c3',
            fill: false,
            data: hourlyData,
            tension: 0.5,
            segment: {
                borderColor: ctx => findEstimate(ctx, '#7c7c7c'), // this works
                pointBackgroundColor: ctx => findEstimate(ctx, '#7c7c7c'), // this does not work
            }
        },
    ],
}

const findEstimate = (ctx, value) => {
    const dt = ctx.p0.$context.raw.gageHeightDateTime
    const start = modalDataRaw.gageHeightDateTimeStart
    const stop = modalDataRaw.gageHeightDateTimeEnd
    if (dt >= start && dt <= stop) {
        return value
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved like this. Just change the condition on context depending your task.

```
const test = (ctx, value) => (ctx.p1DataIndex >= showLast ? value : undefined)

const point = (ctx, trainCol, testCol) => ctx.index >= showLast ? testCol : trainCol


const data = {
labels: trainDates.map(val => val.format("DD-MM")),

datasets: [
  {
    label: "Test plot",
    data: values,
    borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
    fill: false,
    pointStyle: "circle",
    pointBackgroundColor: ctx => point(ctx, "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(192,75,75)"),
    pointBorderColor: ctx => point(ctx, "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(192,75,75)"),
    segment: {
      borderColor: ctx => test(ctx, "rgb(192,75,75)"),
    },
  },
],}
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrLL6.png)